# Magento 2.3.2 sends me to an empty cart instead of thank you page after the payment

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, payment, empty

I'm using Magento 2.3.2, and I noticed that I get sent to an empty cart page after I do the payment. The money are taken and the order gets done, only thing, I want it to get sent to the thank you page, and not an empty cart..

Comment: Something is deleting the customer session after the order is placed. if you have custom order email templates try reverting to the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It happen due to session has been expired. Try by clearing cache, session first and then again try to place an order. If still not work, then try to disable all the third-party extension or custom extension that you installed in it and check it again. It will definitely work.